# Is it possible to add to "Next Button" to a website which has numbered list of pages?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I'm scraping data from a website, but it doesn't have a "Next" button which is required for the tool I'm using. Rather, it has hyperlinked page numbers individually([1,2,3,4...]) . I am not acquainted with web development, although I can code in Java, XML, C and android. Is it possible to make some changes to the HTML code to add a button functionality on the website?Thanks

Comment: What's a "next" button on the web if not a link? Are you saying that your tool doesn't know which page is next in the sequence? You'll probably need to provide more information about your use case.

Comment: @isherwood Yes the tool doesn't know which page is next. For example on google search results there are top 10 pages numbered 1 -10 and there's also a next button which is present on all pages. On this page there's no next button only numbered. The tool can identify the next button if its present on all pages.

Comment: @isherwood Can you take a look at [this](https://www.askapatient.com/viewrating.asp?drug=21073&name=ACTOS&page=1) link? I think you are suggesting parsing of URL for the functionality of button, but is HTML sufficient for this, as well as for adding a UI for the button?

Comment: The question is clear enough for the sake of community, my replies only correspond to the specific queries you made in the comments section.